# Android Ringtone disapear after Mount and Unmount SDcard

Tags: android

I have experienced Ringtone problem while unmount and mount the External SD card.

Here is the Steps:
1. Set music file from external SD card as ringtone;
2. Mount SD card;
3. Unmount SD card;
4. Check ringtone;

Expected result:
Ringtone should be the one set on step1.

Actual result:
Ringtone changed to default ringtone

Please help me which file i need to change to acheive Expected results

Answer (score 0):

Save the current ringtone on the device.   When you unmount device must change to a file not on sd card because it wont ring without ring tone.